# Swift 3.0 converting error

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I have a Swift 2.2 project.
Now I'm trying to convert it to Swift 3.0 but get error.

Swift 2.2 :

```
import QuartzCore.QuartzCore
```

but this code occurs error.

Swift 3.0 error:

```
No such module 'QuartzCore.QuartzCore'
```

Why this error occur and how to fix this error?

Comment: Just `import QuartzCore`

Comment: Just fixed. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
import QuartzCore
```

*Answered by [Hamish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2976878/hamish)*

Answer (score 0):

Just type only `import QuartzCore`

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answer and comment